# FluentValidation throws System.InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, validation, fluent

I updated packages in an .NET Framework project developed using [FluentValidation v8.1.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation.AspNetCore/8.1.3). FluentValidation was upgraded to [v11.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation/946.0.0) when I updated the packages in the project. This update caused an error to be thrown by FluentValidation:

```cs
public static class Utility
{
    public static void Validate(IValidator validator, object entity)
    {
        /* System.InvalidCastException */
        var result = validator.Validate((IValidationContext) validator);

        if (result.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(result.Errors);
        }
    }
}
```

Error details are available below:

```
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'DevFramework.Business.ValidationRules.FluentValidation.CustomerValidator' to type 'FluentValidation.IValidationContext'.'
```

How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Please include the version you are going to in the question. Also see https://docs.fluentvalidation.net/en/latest/upgrading-to-11.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the current version of [FluentValidation v11.1.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/FluentValidation/946.0.0) it is necessary to create a `ValidationContext` object to fix this error.

```cs
public static class Utility
{
    public static void Validate(IValidator validator, object entity)
    {
        /* Notice that the ValidationContext object is created below. */
        var context = new ValidationContext<object>(entity);
        var result = validator.Validate(context);

        if (result.Errors.Count > 0)
        {
            throw new ValidationException(result.Errors);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the only working solution I could find. Works with inheritance to set a derived class specific validator, so base can implement a paramless Validate()